# Given an number N, how to count the number of all m and n int pairs such that m*m + n*n < N?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

The naive solution would be to have a O(sqrtRoot of N) search for all pairs but there should be a smarter solution...

I was hinted to use a threaded binary tree... Any idea?

Comment: What's wrong with O(sqrt(N))? If you're required to explicitly list all pairs, you can't even get O(sqrt(N)), since you have to return O(N) results.

Comment: Do you need to *count* the pairs, or do you need to list all of them?

Comment: Note that for listing them, if you can get away with listing all maximal pairs (ones in which you can't increase m or n and still fit the constraint), you can still get O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: Sorry the problem is find the number of count, just updated

Comment: @ArrowCen For reference, the problem you're trying to solve is called the [Gauss circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a ballpark figure, and N is sufficiently large, you can answer in O(1): if you are interested in non-negative (m,n) pairs just reply pi*N*N/4; if you allow negatives reply pi*N*N.

Noticing that each pair (m,n) such that m*m+n*n < N, m>0, n>0 corresponds to a point inside upper right quadrant inside a disk of radius sqrt(N). The area of such quarter-disk is pi*N*N/4. Each point (m,n) corresponds to a 1x1 square. Therefore you can expect approximately pi*N*N/4 such pairs to cover all the area of the quarter-disk.

If you need a precise number then I don't know of any algorithm that would run faster than O(sqrt(N)).

Comment: [This MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19079/what-is-the-status-of-the-gauss-circle-problem) is related: it refers to a result that states that the estimate in the answer is closer that one would expect.